# Loop for a list of names

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to work on my first loops in R - it seems a bit different to bash though.

I wrote a script in which I only have to enter a gene name as variable
gene_name <- c("ABCD")

everything else including saving files with a different file name is working. I just cannot get it to work. The structure of the gene_list table is just different headings with conditions and below just gene names.

```
genelist <- read.csv("gene_list.csv",head=T,row.names=NULL, dec = ".")

for (i in genelist$condA) {
gene_name <- c([i])
.
command pipeline...

}
```

the error that I get is:

```
Error: unexpected '[' in:    
"for (i in genelist$condA) {

  gene_name <- c(["
```

Is there any good tutorial or any easy fix to get this to work. in the command line later I am executing many other things but beside changing my gene_name variable everything is copy & paste and fully automated.
Thank you so much!!
 D

Comment: Did you meant `for(i in seq_along(genelist$condA)) { gene_name <- genelist$condA[i]`

Comment: wow this was fast and worked! Thanks! if you know a good tutorial for R loops would be amazing. thanks again for the rapid response! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we are looping through the sequence of the column and then create an object 'gene_name', then use the index ('i') to subset the 'condA' value

```
for(i in seq_along(genelist$condA)) {
    gene_name <- genelist$condA[i]
 ..
 ..
}
```